# ANTLR4 Checking a Node's Parent in the Parse Tree

Tags: antlr4

When processing my ANTLR4 parse tree by a visitor, sometimes I need to know the parent rule nodes that my rule node is under. In the online API documentation for `ParserRuleContext`, I find no method/field that can return the name of the rule that an object is representing. I know the rule name is part of the `ParserRuleContext`'s subclass name e.g. `function_definition` rule node is class `Function_definitionContext`.  But to enquire the class name I need to use Java reflection and manually stripe the `Context` string at the end.

Is there is simpler method to retrieve the rule name that a `ParserRuleContext` object is representing?

It is a common requirement to enquire the parent rule node's name.  For example, when processing the C++ grammar, a C++ class declaration can be in a global scope, function definition, or another class declaration which means a rule node `class_declaration` can be nested under a `global_scope`, `function_definition` or `class_declaration` rule node.  If I want to isolate only those `class_declaration` nodes under the `global_scope`, I need to look up the parent nodes and make sure that they're not `function_definition` or `class_declaration`.

Comment: Did you find  how to get the parent rule from the given rule?

Comment: MysticForce: yes, the rule name can be found by the methods described by Sam's answer. The parent node is found by RuleContext.getParent()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the rule name from a `ParserRuleContext` as a string, you can do this:

```
String[] ruleNames = parser.getRuleNames();
String ruleName = ruleNames[parserRuleContext.getRuleIndex()];
```

You can also compare the rule index against the generated constants:

```
boolean isClassDeclaration =
    parserRuleContext.getRuleIndex() == MyParser.RULE_class_declaration;
```

Comment: Now how to do this in the listener?